# ShadowBox Js - open videos in fullscreen directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, fullscreen, shadowbox

Is there a way to configure shadowBox to open up videos in fullscreen directly? I want this when you surf on the site with a mobile device instead of a popup.

Comment: shadowplayer? do you mean ShadowBox?

Comment: @DušanRadojević - Yeah, sorry... type..

Answer (score 0):

If you are embeding flash based video players then answer is no. 
Since there are security restrictions by which you can not call video full screen mode from javascript or from any other place that is outside of flash environment.

But you can make some pseudo full screen by placing your video player in some DIV that has width and height 100% and make some GUI elements and javascript logic to close that DIV on some event like onclick.

In case your video is HTML based, video tag you can call full screen mode from javascript.
More on calling full screen on video tag from javascript can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FUsing_full-screen_mode